# AWS CodeDeploy fails: Script at specified location run as user ubuntu failed with exit code 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

If I try to run deployment from a GitHub project to EC2 Instance using AWS CodeDeploy, I get these error messages from `/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log`

```
2022-08-02 08:33:57 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(5871)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.3.2-1902_deb.
2022-08-02 08:33:57 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(5871)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.029191 0 retries] get_deployment_specification(deployment_execution_id:"CodeDeploy/us-east-2/prod/orpheus:public005/020801435925:d-GW7F45ARH",host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:020801435925:instance/i-087157ab53b339170")  

2022-08-02 08:33:58 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(5871)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.3.2-1902_deb.
2022-08-02 08:33:58 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(5871)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.048105 0 retries] put_host_command_complete(command_status:"Failed",diagnostics:{format:"JSON",payload:"{\"error_code\":4,\"script_name\":\"scripts/application_stop.sh\",\"message\":\"Script at specified location: scripts/application_stop.sh run as user ubuntu failed with exit code 1\",\"log\":\"LifecycleEvent - ApplicationStop\\nScript - scripts/application_stop.sh\\n[stderr][PM2][ERROR] Process or Namespace pm2stage not found\\n[stderr][PM2][ERROR] Process or Namespace pm2stage not found\\n\"}"},host_command_identifier:"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")  

2022-08-02 08:33:58 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(5871)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Error during perform: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::ScriptError - Script at specified location: scripts/application_stop.sh run as user ubuntu failed with exit code 1 - /opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:183:in `execute_script'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:129:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:117:in `each'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:117:in `block in execute'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:208:in `create_script_log_file_if_needed'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:115:in `execute'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_executor.rb:160:in `block (3 levels) in map'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_executor.rb:148:in `each'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_executor.rb:148:in `block (2 levels) in map'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_executor.rb:70:in `execute_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_poller.rb:115:in `process_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_poller.rb:97:in `acknowledge_and_process_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_poller.rb:76:in `block in perform'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:348:in `run_task'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:337:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:320:in `loop'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:320:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:319:in `catch'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:319:in `block in create_worker'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/logging-1.8.2/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:323:in `block in create_with_logging_context'
2022-08-02 08:33:58 WARN  [codedeploy-agent(5871)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Calling PutHostCommandComplete: "Code Error" 
2022-08-02 08:33:58 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(5871)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.3.2-1902_deb.
2022-08-02 08:33:58 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(5871)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.3.2-1902_deb.
2022-08-02 08:33:58 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(5871)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.026917 0 retries] put_host_command_complete(command_status:"Failed",diagnostics:{format:"JSON",payload:"{\"error_code\":5,\"script_name\":\"\",\"message\":\"Script at specified location: scripts/application_stop.sh run as user ubuntu failed with exit code 1\",\"log\":\"\"}"},host_command_identifier:"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")  

2022-08-02 08:34:43 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(5871)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 45.11025 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:020801435925:instance/i-087157ab53b339170")  

2022-08-02 08:34:44 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(5871)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.3.2-1902_deb.
2022-08-02 08:35:29 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(5871)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 45.141769 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:020801435925:instance/i-087157ab53b339170")  

2022-08-02 08:35:30 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(5871)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.3.2-1902_deb.
2022-08-02 08:36:16 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(5871)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 45.391621 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:020801435925:instance/i-087157ab53b339170")
```

I don't understand what does it mean:

```
InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Error during perform: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::ScriptError - Script at specified location: scripts/application_stop.sh run as user ubuntu failed with exit code 1
```

**appspec.yml**

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/apps/cbl_stage/cbl-backend
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/before_install.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: ubuntu
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/after_install.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: ubuntu
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/application_start.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: ubuntu
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/application_stop.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: ubuntu
```

**before_install.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

#download node and npm
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install 16.16.0

#create our working directory if it doesnt exist
DIR="/var/apps/cbl_stage/cbl-backend"
if [ -d "$DIR" ]; then
  echo "${DIR} exists"
else
  echo "Creating ${DIR} directory"
  mkdir ${DIR}
fi
```

**after_install.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

#give permission for everything in the express-app directory
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/apps/cbl_stage/cbl-backend

#add npm and node to path
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" 
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # loads nvm   
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # loads nvm bash_completion (node is in path now)

#navigate into our working directory where we have all our github files
cd /var/apps/cbl_stage/cbl-backend

#install node modules
npm ci
npm install pm2 -g

#migrate database
npx sequelize-cli db:migrate --env test
npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all --env test
```

**application_start.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

#add npm and node to path
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" 
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # loads nvm   
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # loads nvm bash_completion (node is in path now)

#navigate into our working directory where we have all our github files
cd /var/apps/cbl_stage/cbl-backend

#start our node app in the background
pm2 start "NODE_ENV=test ./bin/www" --name pm2stage --watch
```

**application_stop.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

#add npm and node to path
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" 
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # loads nvm   
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # loads nvm bash_completion (node is in path now)

#navigate into our working directory where we have all our github files
cd /var/apps/cbl_stage/cbl-backend

pm2 stop pm2stage
pm2 delete pm2stage
```

Comment: Can you show your codedeploy config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well. The line

> put_host_command_complete(command_status:"Failed",diagnostics:{format:"JSON",payload:"{"error_code":4,"script_name":"scripts/application_stop.sh","message":"Script at specified location: scripts/application_stop.sh run as user ubuntu failed with exit code 1","log":"LifecycleEvent - ApplicationStop\nScript - scripts/application_stop.sh\n[stderr][PM2][ERROR] Process or Namespace pm2stage not found\n[stderr][PM2][ERROR] Process or Namespace pm2stage not found\n"}"},.....)

says it all. Either of these commands:

```
pm2 stop pm2stage

pm2 delete pm2stage
```

is failing simply because `pm2stage` doesn't exist. It's either already stopped or not present because of a previous legitimate CI/CD failure. There are several ways by which you can handle it:

- **Check for the process before stopping or deleting it.**

```html
#!/bin/bash
pm2 describe appname > /dev/null
RUNNING=$?

if [ "${RUNNING}" -ne 0 ]; then
  pm2 start ./deploy/development.yml
else
  pm2 restart appname
fi;
```

- **Ignore the exit code errors**

  1. Using `--silent` param:

     ```
     pm2 stop --silent pm2stage

     pm2 delete --silent pm2stage
     ```
  2. Using `|| :`:

     ```
     pm2 stop pm2stage || :

     pm2 delete pm2stage || :
     ```
- **Ignore the error output in CodeDeploy console before deployment**

  You can choose to ignore the error in the `ApplicationStop` lifecycle event and continue with deployment. Under `ApplicationStop lifecycle event failure`, check the box that says `Don’t fail the deployment to an instance if this lifecycle event on the instance fails`. See screenshot for reference:

[image]